# Why is a difference between קדשי מזבח and קדשי בדק הבית listed among their similarities?

Tags: mishna, hekdesh, maseches-temura

[The *Mishna*, at the start of chapter 7 of *T'mura*](//www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Temurah.7), in my own, loose translation:

> Things that are sanctified [i.e., pledged, donated] for the altar have [rules] that do not apply to things that are sanctified for [the expenses of] temple upkeep, and vice versa:
>
> - Things sanctified for the altar … [have a bunch of rules].
> - And things sanctified for temple upkeep have, which things sanctified for the altar do not: … [a bunch of rules].
>
> Both things sanctified for the altar and things sanctified for temple upkeep: You cannot change them from one holiness to another. And you can sanctify them a high sanctity and *cherem*. And if they die, they're buried.

The commentaries explain what those last three rules are, and I won't go into them. But they note that the "you can sanctify them a high sanctity and *cherem*" applies only to things that had been sanctified for the altar and not to things that had been sanctified for temple upkeep.

So why's it on this list and not on one of the first two lists?